# Table Headers Losing Formatting After Adding Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an actual table (`ListObject`):

[image]

I am trying to add a new row in row 29. Because I have another table below I am using `Rows.Insert` method.

My simple code:

`Activesheet.Rows(29).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow`

The problem is when I run this code, my table formatting ends up like the below and I am **unable** to change the background colour of the headers manually.

[image]

Now, even more interesting, when I insert a row **manually** it works fine, seen below.

[image]

Using the Macro Recorder (cringe) from inserting the row manually I get the below code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("29:29").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Interestingly, if I use `CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove` in my code this is what gets returned in my table (expected):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it an actual table (`ListObject`)?

Comment: @BigBen yes it is

Comment: So... I'm assuming you don't use `ListRows.Add` because of the other table below, or am I missing something?

Comment: @BigBen yes you are correct, as I state above.

Comment: Is it an option to insert a row/cells between the tables (to make sure they won't overlap), and then use `ListRows.Add`?

Comment: @BigBen the tables are different sizes, the lower being across more columns. I have assessed using `ListRows.Add`, but it doesn't seem to be an option unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though